# Подключение к базе данных в Python

Tags: python-3.x, драйвер, odbc

Пытаюсь подключиться к SQL серверу. Пример кода ниже.
При подключении получаю ошибку.

> ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию')

В источнике данных(ODBC) драйвера установлены.
Пробовал разные драйвера, ошибка одна и та же. Не могу понять чего не хватает.

```
import sys
import pypyodbc

try:
    conn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver = {ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}; Server = NameServer; uid = sa; pwd = '
                            'myPassword; Database = BaseName')

except Exception:
    print("Ошибка")
    print(sys.exc_info()[2])
else:
    print("Подключение")
    conn.close()
```

Вот так выглядит окно DNS. Куда нужно добавлять Драйвера? В пользовательский или системный?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я добавил драйвер. Ошибка осталась.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал через pymssql. Код заработал к базе подключился.

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server='serv', user='sa', password='PWD', database='DBname')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT IM FROM BID")
row = cursor.fetchone()
for a in row:
    print(a)
conn.close()
```

Но все таки хочу понять почему не работает через pypyodbc. Дело явно в драйвере.
Может есть какие-то нюансы при добавлении в DNS? Или может Питон не все драйверы поддерживает? Или может я использую не правильную строку подключения?

Answer (score 1):

Надо создать в панели управления -> Источники данных ODBC 32/64bit -> системный DSN с указанием нужных параметров.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй через SQLAlchemy:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
con = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://логин:пароль@сервер/База')
```